# LESS.js compiles css but doesn't apply it?

Tags: css, compilation, less

I have included the style.less file and the less.js file in the header, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/less" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/style.less" media="screen">
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/libs/less-1.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've checked the source and both files are loaded just fine. In the style.less file I have a couple of imported files. When the page loads and I check the console, I can see that all of the imported files are fetched. But for some reason, no styling is applied to the page:

[image]

I have compiled the file locally with no problems, so I know for a fact there's nothing wrong with the code.

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type to `text/css` and it should work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `type` is optional anyway, but the `rel` is needed and it has the correct value. I tried changing `type` to `text/css` but no success. :(

Comment: Try by using only once less file with full path if needed.. just to see if your less.js is actually compiling at least one before trying with multiple.

Comment: and don't forget that you can use one .less file and then inside this one @include the rest.. so you don't have to load in html multiple styles

Comment: I believe it's called `@import` and not `@include`, but either way that is what i am doing. I know for a fact it does compile because otherwise it wouldn't have fetched the other less files (which are imported through less). *Edit:* See: http://lesscss.org/#-importing

Comment: yep... sorry it's `@import`, but either case.. can you try if it compiles with the minimum .less file possible.. just to debug it and then start adding more and more.. because it looks like you're doing fine and it should work.. and I'm guessing something is crashing it.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right. I created a test file that just fades the body a bit, and it works just fine. So, is there any way to see what exactly causes this?

Comment: not exactly but now all you have to do is to start adding one file at the time.. to see where it stops working.. when you'll find that file.. remove all the others and make sure that this single files is also compiling.. There is something wrong in one of the files so you'll have to track it down if there are no error messages in the console.. try doing that in Chrome if not already for better console.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28734/discussion-between-lipis-and-qwerty)